# AppEngine mapper API import error

Tags: python, google-app-engine, import, importerror

EDIT: I just gave it a go on appengine itself and it seems like it actually works there, so the problem is just with the dev server. I would still be interested in understanding why this is happening...

I am using the AppEngine mapper API (mapreduce) and am having a problem with imports. Here is my file structure:

```
├── [ost               12]  app.yaml -> src/app.yaml
├── [ost             4096]  doc
├── [ost              615]  fabfile.py
├── [ost               18]  gae -> /home/ost/dev/gae/
├── [ost               70]  INFO
├── [ost                0]  LICENSE
├── [ost                5]  README
├── [ost               38]  run_clean
├── [ost               64]  run_deploy
├── [ost               83]  run_pylint
├── [ost               78]  run_tests
├── [ost             4096]  src
│   ├── [ost             4096]  admin
│   ├── [ost              504]  app.yaml
│   ├── [ost             4822]  data.py
│   ├── [ost             4096]  dhandler
│   ├── [ost             2273]  ds.html
│   ├── [ost             5424]  generator.py
│   ├── [ost                0]  __init__.py
│   ├── [ost             3527]  lib.py
│   ├── [ost             4211]  main.py
│   ├── [ost              457]  mappers.py
│   ├── [ost              298]  mapreduce.yaml
│   ├── [ost             4192]  parser.py
│   └── [ost             4096]  static
├── [ost             4096]  test
│   └── [ost             2445]  test_data.py
└── [ost               98]  TODO
```

My app.yaml is:

```
application: <removed>
version: 1
runtime: python
api_version: 1

builtins:
- datastore_admin: on
- appstats: on

handlers:
- url: /remote_api
  script: $PYTHON_LIB/google/appengine/ext/remote_api/handler.py
  login: admin

- url: /admin
  script: admin/admin.py
  login: admin

- url: /dhandler/.*
  script: dhandler/dhandler.py

- url: /mapreduce(/.*)?
  script: $PYTHON_LIB/google/appengine/ext/mapreduce/main.py
  login: admin

- url: /static
  static_dir: static

- url: /.*
  script: main.py
```

My mapreduce.yaml:

```
mapreduce:
- name: insert-domain-mapper
  params:
  - name: done_callback
    value: /dhandler/insert_job_done
  mapper:
    input_reader: google.appengine.ext.mapreduce.input_readers.BlobstoreLineInputReader
    handler: mappers.insert_domain
    params:
    - name: blob_keys
      default: ""
```

Finally mappers.py

```
from  google.appengine.ext.mapreduce import operation as op

from data import RegisteredDomain, make_key, clean_domain

def insert_domain((byte_offset, line)):

    domain = line

    # TODO: domain validity check (??)

    # clean domain
    domain = clean_domain(domain)

    # create domain entity
    domain_entity = RegisteredDomain(key_name=make_key(domain))

    # yield put operation
    yield op.db.Put(domain_entity)
```

Now the problem is that, although I can load the /mapreduce page and the job is available, as soon as I try to start the job I get the following error (on the page):

```
ImportError: Could not find 'input_readers' on path 'google.appengine.ext.mapreduce'
```

Here is a complete stack trace:

```
DEBUG    2011-09-28 18:30:54,829 dev_appserver.py:3022] Executing CGI with env:
{'HTTP_ACCEPT': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8', 'HTTP_CONNECTION': 'keep-alive',
'CONTENT_TYPE': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded', 'HTTP_COOKIE': 'dev_appserver_login="test@example.com:True:1858
04764220139124118"', 'HTTP_ACCEPT_CHARSET': 'ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3', 'CURRENT_VERSION_ID': '1.1', 'SERVER_S
OFTWARE': 'Development/1.0', 'SCRIPT_NAME': '', 'USER_ORGANIZATION': '', 'REQUEST_METHOD': 'GET', 'HTTP_HOST': '10.1
.2.20:8000', 'PATH_INFO': '/mapreduce/status', 'SERVER_PROTOCOL': 'HTTP/1.0', 'QUERY_STRING': '', 'TZ': 'UTC', 'HTTP
_CACHE_CONTROL': 'max-age=0', 'USER_EMAIL': 'test@example.com', 'USER_IS_ADMIN': '1', 'CONTENT_LENGTH': '', 'USER_ID
': '185804764220139124118', 'HTTP_USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/535.2 (KHTML, like G
ecko) Chrome/15.0.874.24 Safari/535.2', 'APPLICATION_ID': 'dev~domain-sandwich', 'SERVER_NAME': '10.1.2.20', 'REMOTE
_ADDR': '10.1.2.5', 'GATEWAY_INTERFACE': 'CGI/1.1', 'HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE': 'en-US,en;q=0.8', 'SDK_VERSION': '1.5.2'
, 'PATH_TRANSLATED': '/home/ost/dev/gae/google/appengine/ext/mapreduce/main.py', 'SERVER_PORT': '8000', 'AUTH_DOMAIN
': 'gmail.com'}
DEBUG    2011-09-28 18:30:54,830 dev_appserver.py:2721] Reusing main() function of module "google.appengine.ext.mapr
educe.main"

    INFO     2011-09-28 18:30:54,841 dev_appserver.py:4248] "GET /mapreduce/status HTTP/1.1" 200 -
    DEBUG    2011-09-28 18:30:54,843 dev_appserver_index.py:172] No need to update index.yaml
    DEBUG    2011-09-28 18:30:54,890 dev_appserver.py:589] Matched "/mapreduce/base.css" to CGI dispatcher with path $PY
    THON_LIB/google/appengine/ext/mapreduce/main.py
    DEBUG    2011-09-28 18:30:54,894 dev_appserver.py:3022] Executing CGI with env:
    {'HTTP_ACCEPT': 'text/css,*/*;q=0.1', 'HTTP_CONNECTION': 'keep-alive', 'CONTENT_TYPE': 'application/x-www-form-urlen
    coded', 'HTTP_REFERER': 'http://10.1.2.20:8000/mapreduce/status', 'HTTP_ACCEPT_CHARSET': 'ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q
    =0.3', 'CURRENT_VERSION_ID': '1.1', 'SERVER_SOFTWARE': 'Development/1.0', 'SCRIPT_NAME': '', 'USER_ORGANIZATION': ''
    , 'REQUEST_METHOD': 'GET', 'HTTP_HOST': '10.1.2.20:8000', 'PATH_INFO': '/mapreduce/base.css', 'SERVER_PROTOCOL': 'HT
    TP/1.0', 'QUERY_STRING': '', 'TZ': 'UTC', 'USER_EMAIL': 'test@example.com', 'USER_IS_ADMIN': '1', 'CONTENT_LENGTH':
    '', 'USER_ID': '185804764220139124118', 'HTTP_USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/535.2 (K
    HTML, like Gecko) Chrome/15.0.874.24 Safari/535.2', 'APPLICATION_ID': 'dev~domain-sandwich', 'HTTP_COOKIE': 'dev_app
    server_login="test@example.com:True:185804764220139124118"', 'SERVER_NAME': '10.1.2.20', 'REMOTE_ADDR': '10.1.2.5',
    'GATEWAY_INTERFACE': 'CGI/1.1', 'HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE': 'en-US,en;q=0.8', 'SDK_VERSION': '1.5.2', 'PATH_TRANSLATED':
     '/home/ost/dev/gae/google/appengine/ext/mapreduce/main.py', 'SERVER_PORT': '8000', 'AUTH_DOMAIN': 'gmail.com'}
    DEBUG    2011-09-28 18:30:54,895 dev_appserver.py:2721] Reusing main() function of module "google.appengine.ext.mapr
    educe.main"
    INFO     2011-09-28 18:30:54,902 dev_appserver.py:4248] "GET /mapreduce/base.css HTTP/1.1" 200 -
    DEBUG    2011-09-28 18:30:54,903 dev_appserver_index.py:172] No need to update index.yaml
    DEBUG    2011-09-28 18:30:54,911 dev_appserver.py:589] Matched "/mapreduce/jquery.js" to CGI dispatcher with path $P
    YTHON_LIB/google/appengine/ext/mapreduce/main.py
    DEBUG    2011-09-28 18:30:54,915 dev_appserver.py:3022] Executing CGI with env:
    {'HTTP_ACCEPT': '*/*', 'HTTP_CONNECTION': 'keep-alive', 'CONTENT_TYPE': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded', 'HTTP_R
    EFERER': 'http://10.1.2.20:8000/mapreduce/status', 'HTTP_ACCEPT_CHARSET': 'ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3', 'CURRENT
    _VERSION_ID': '1.1', 'SERVER_SOFTWARE': 'Development/1.0', 'SCRIPT_NAME': '', 'USER_ORGANIZATION': '', 'REQUEST_METH
    OD': 'GET', 'HTTP_HOST': '10.1.2.20:8000', 'PATH_INFO': '/mapreduce/jquery.js', 'SERVER_PROTOCOL': 'HTTP/1.0', 'QUER
    Y_STRING': '', 'TZ': 'UTC', 'USER_EMAIL': 'test@example.com', 'USER_IS_ADMIN': '1', 'CONTENT_LENGTH': '', 'USER_ID':
     '185804764220139124118', 'HTTP_USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/535.2 (KHTML, like Gec
    ko) Chrome/15.0.874.24 Safari/535.2', 'APPLICATION_ID': 'dev~domain-sandwich', 'HTTP_COOKIE': 'dev_appserver_login="
    test@example.com:True:185804764220139124118"', 'SERVER_NAME': '10.1.2.20', 'REMOTE_ADDR': '10.1.2.5', 'GATEWAY_INTER
    FACE': 'CGI/1.1', 'HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE': 'en-US,en;q=0.8', 'SDK_VERSION': '1.5.2', 'PATH_TRANSLATED': '/home/ost/de
    v/gae/google/appengine/ext/mapreduce/main.py', 'SERVER_PORT': '8000', 'AUTH_DOMAIN': 'gmail.com'}
    DEBUG    2011-09-28 18:30:54,916 dev_appserver.py:2721] Reusing main() function of module "google.appengine.ext.mapr
    educe.main"
    INFO     2011-09-28 18:30:54,924 dev_appserver.py:4248] "GET /mapreduce/jquery.js HTTP/1.1" 200 -
    DEBUG    2011-09-28 18:30:54,931 dev_appserver_index.py:172] No need to update index.yaml
    DEBUG    2011-09-28 18:30:54,938 dev_appserver.py:589] Matched "/mapreduce/status.js" to CGI dispatcher with path $P
    YTHON_LIB/google/appengine/ext/mapreduce/main.py
    DEBUG    2011-09-28 18:30:54,942 dev_appserver.py:3022] Executing CGI with env:
    {'HTTP_ACCEPT': '*/*', 'HTTP_CONNECTION': 'keep-alive', 'CONTENT_TYPE': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded', 'HTTP_R
    EFERER': 'http://10.1.2.20:8000/mapreduce/status', 'HTTP_ACCEPT_CHARSET': 'ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3', 'CURRENT
    _VERSION_ID': '1.1', 'SERVER_SOFTWARE': 'Development/1.0', 'SCRIPT_NAME': '', 'USER_ORGANIZATION': '', 'REQUEST_METH
    OD': 'GET', 'HTTP_HOST': '10.1.2.20:8000', 'PATH_INFO': '/mapreduce/status.js', 'SERVER_PROTOCOL': 'HTTP/1.0', 'QUER
    Y_STRING': '', 'TZ': 'UTC', 'USER_EMAIL': 'test@example.com', 'USER_IS_ADMIN': '1', 'CONTENT_LENGTH': '', 'USER_ID':
     '185804764220139124118', 'HTTP_USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/535.2 (KHTML, like Gec
    ko) Chrome/15.0.874.24 Safari/535.2', 'APPLICATION_ID': 'dev~domain-sandwich', 'HTTP_COOKIE': 'dev_appserver_login="
    test@example.com:True:185804764220139124118"', 'SERVER_NAME': '10.1.2.20', 'REMOTE_ADDR': '10.1.2.5', 'GATEWAY_INTER
    FACE': 'CGI/1.1', 'HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE': 'en-US,en;q=0.8', 'SDK_VERSION': '1.5.2', 'PATH_TRANSLATED': '/home/ost/de
    v/gae/google/appengine/ext/mapreduce/main.py', 'SERVER_PORT': '8000', 'AUTH_DOMAIN': 'gmail.com'}
    DEBUG    2011-09-28 18:30:54,943 dev_appserver.py:2721] Reusing main() function of module "google.appengine.ext.mapr
    educe.main"
    INFO     2011-09-28 18:30:54,951 dev_appserver.py:4248] "GET /mapreduce/status.js HTTP/1.1" 200 -
    DEBUG    2011-09-28 18:30:54,953 dev_appserver_index.py:172] No need to update index.yaml
    DEBUG    2011-09-28 18:30:54,972 dev_appserver.py:589] Matched "/mapreduce/command/list_configs" to CGI dispatcher w
    ith path $PYTHON_LIB/google/appengine/ext/mapreduce/main.py
    DEBUG    2011-09-28 18:30:54,976 dev_appserver.py:3022] Executing CGI with env:
    {'HTTP_ACCEPT': 'text/plain, */*', 'HTTP_CONNECTION': 'keep-alive', 'USER_IS_ADMIN': '1', 'HTTP_COOKIE': 'dev_appser
    ver_login="test@example.com:True:185804764220139124118"', 'CURRENT_VERSION_ID': '1.1', 'SERVER_SOFTWARE': 'Developme
    nt/1.0', 'SCRIPT_NAME': '', 'USER_ORGANIZATION': '', 'USER_ID': '185804764220139124118', 'REQUEST_METHOD': 'GET', 'H
    TTP_HOST': '10.1.2.20:8000', 'PATH_INFO': '/mapreduce/command/list_configs', 'SERVER_PROTOCOL': 'HTTP/1.0', 'QUERY_S
    TRING': '', 'TZ': 'UTC', 'HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH': 'XMLHttpRequest', 'USER_EMAIL': 'test@example.com', 'CONTENT_LENGT
    H': '', 'HTTP_ACCEPT_CHARSET': 'ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3', 'HTTP_USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WO
    W64) AppleWebKit/535.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/15.0.874.24 Safari/535.2', 'APPLICATION_ID': 'dev~domain-sandwich'
    , 'HTTP_REFERER': 'http://10.1.2.20:8000/mapreduce/status', 'SERVER_NAME': '10.1.2.20', 'REMOTE_ADDR': '10.1.2.5', '
    CONTENT_TYPE': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded', 'GATEWAY_INTERFACE': 'CGI/1.1', 'HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE': 'en-US,e
    n;q=0.8', 'SDK_VERSION': '1.5.2', 'PATH_TRANSLATED': '/home/ost/dev/gae/google/appengine/ext/mapreduce/main.py', 'SE
    RVER_PORT': '8000', 'AUTH_DOMAIN': 'gmail.com'}
    DEBUG    2011-09-28 18:30:54,977 dev_appserver.py:2721] Reusing main() function of module "google.appengine.ext.mapr
    educe.main"
    INFO     2011-09-28 18:30:54,991 dev_appserver.py:4248] "GET /mapreduce/command/list_configs HTTP/1.1" 200 -
    DEBUG    2011-09-28 18:30:54,992 dev_appserver_index.py:172] No need to update index.yaml
    DEBUG    2011-09-28 18:30:54,999 dev_appserver.py:589] Matched "/mapreduce/command/list_jobs" to CGI dispatcher with
     path $PYTHON_LIB/google/appengine/ext/mapreduce/main.py
    DEBUG    2011-09-28 18:30:55,003 dev_appserver.py:3022] Executing CGI with env:
    {'HTTP_ACCEPT': 'text/plain, */*', 'HTTP_CONNECTION': 'keep-alive', 'USER_IS_ADMIN': '1', 'HTTP_COOKIE': 'dev_appser
    ver_login="test@example.com:True:185804764220139124118"', 'CURRENT_VERSION_ID': '1.1', 'SERVER_SOFTWARE': 'Developme
    nt/1.0', 'SCRIPT_NAME': '', 'USER_ORGANIZATION': '', 'USER_ID': '185804764220139124118', 'REQUEST_METHOD': 'GET', 'H
    TTP_HOST': '10.1.2.20:8000', 'PATH_INFO': '/mapreduce/command/list_jobs', 'SERVER_PROTOCOL': 'HTTP/1.0', 'QUERY_STRI
    NG': '', 'TZ': 'UTC', 'HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH': 'XMLHttpRequest', 'USER_EMAIL': 'test@example.com', 'CONTENT_LENGTH':
     '', 'HTTP_ACCEPT_CHARSET': 'ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3', 'HTTP_USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64
    ) AppleWebKit/535.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/15.0.874.24 Safari/535.2', 'APPLICATION_ID': 'dev~domain-sandwich', '
    HTTP_REFERER': 'http://10.1.2.20:8000/mapreduce/status', 'SERVER_NAME': '10.1.2.20', 'REMOTE_ADDR': '10.1.2.5', 'CON
    TENT_TYPE': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded', 'GATEWAY_INTERFACE': 'CGI/1.1', 'HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE': 'en-US,en;q
    =0.8', 'SDK_VERSION': '1.5.2', 'PATH_TRANSLATED': '/home/ost/dev/gae/google/appengine/ext/mapreduce/main.py', 'SERVE
    R_PORT': '8000', 'AUTH_DOMAIN': 'gmail.com'}
    DEBUG    2011-09-28 18:30:55,003 dev_appserver.py:2721] Reusing main() function of module "google.appengine.ext.mapr
    educe.main"
    INFO     2011-09-28 18:30:55,012 dev_appserver.py:4248] "GET /mapreduce/command/list_jobs HTTP/1.1" 200 -
    DEBUG    2011-09-28 18:30:55,013 dev_appserver_index.py:172] No need to update index.yaml
    DEBUG    2011-09-28 18:30:55,019 dev_appserver.py:589] Matched "/favicon.ico" to CGI dispatcher with path main.py
    DEBUG    2011-09-28 18:30:55,022 dev_appserver.py:3022] Executing CGI with env:
    {'HTTP_ACCEPT': '*/*', 'HTTP_CONNECTION': 'keep-alive', 'CONTENT_TYPE': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded', 'HTTP_C
    OOKIE': 'dev_appserver_login="test@example.com:True:185804764220139124118"', 'HTTP_ACCEPT_CHARSET': 'ISO-8859-1,utf-
    8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3', 'CURRENT_VERSION_ID': '1.1', 'SERVER_SOFTWARE': 'Development/1.0', 'SCRIPT_NAME': '', 'USER_ORGANI
    ZATION': '', 'REQUEST_METHOD': 'GET', 'HTTP_HOST': '10.1.2.20:8000', 'PATH_INFO': '/favicon.ico', 'SERVER_PROTOCOL':
     'HTTP/1.0', 'QUERY_STRING': '', 'TZ': 'UTC', 'USER_EMAIL': 'test@example.com', 'USER_IS_ADMIN': '1', 'CONTENT_LENGT
    H': '', 'USER_ID': '185804764220139124118', 'HTTP_USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/535.
    2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/15.0.874.24 Safari/535.2', 'APPLICATION_ID': 'dev~domain-sandwich', 'SERVER_NAME': '10.
    1.2.20', 'REMOTE_ADDR': '10.1.2.5', 'GATEWAY_INTERFACE': 'CGI/1.1', 'HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE': 'en-US,en;q=0.8', 'SDK_V
    ERSION': '1.5.2', 'PATH_TRANSLATED': '/home/ost/dev/domain-sandwich/src/main.py', 'SERVER_PORT': '8000', 'AUTH_DOMAI
    N': 'gmail.com'}
    DEBUG    2011-09-28 18:30:55,022 dev_appserver.py:2721] Reusing main() function of module "main"
    INFO     2011-09-28 18:30:55,028 dev_appserver.py:4248] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 -
    DEBUG    2011-09-28 18:30:55,029 dev_appserver_index.py:172] No need to update index.yaml
    DEBUG    2011-09-28 18:30:56,662 dev_appserver.py:589] Matched "/mapreduce/command/start_job" to CGI dispatcher with
     path $PYTHON_LIB/google/appengine/ext/mapreduce/main.py
    DEBUG    2011-09-28 18:30:56,670 dev_appserver.py:3022] Executing CGI with env:
    {'HTTP_COOKIE': 'dev_appserver_login="test@example.com:True:185804764220139124118"', 'SERVER_SOFTWARE': 'Development
    /1.0', 'SCRIPT_NAME': '', 'REQUEST_METHOD': 'POST', 'PATH_INFO': '/mapreduce/command/start_job', 'HTTP_ORIGIN': 'htt
    p://10.1.2.20:8000', 'SERVER_PROTOCOL': 'HTTP/1.0', 'QUERY_STRING': '', 'CONTENT_LENGTH': '232', 'HTTP_ACCEPT_CHARSE
    T': 'ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3', 'HTTP_USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/535.2 (KHT
    ML, like Gecko) Chrome/15.0.874.24 Safari/535.2', 'TZ': 'UTC', 'HTTP_REFERER': 'http://10.1.2.20:8000/mapreduce/stat
    us', 'SERVER_NAME': '10.1.2.20', 'REMOTE_ADDR': '10.1.2.5', 'SDK_VERSION': '1.5.2', 'PATH_TRANSLATED': '/home/ost/de
    v/gae/google/appengine/ext/mapreduce/main.py', 'SERVER_PORT': '8000', 'USER_IS_ADMIN': '1', 'HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH':
     'XMLHttpRequest', 'CURRENT_VERSION_ID': '1.1', 'USER_ORGANIZATION': '', 'USER_ID': '185804764220139124118', 'HTTP_H
    OST': '10.1.2.20:8000', 'HTTP_CONNECTION': 'keep-alive', 'USER_EMAIL': 'test@example.com', 'HTTP_ACCEPT': 'text/plai
    n, */*', 'APPLICATION_ID': 'dev~domain-sandwich', 'GATEWAY_INTERFACE': 'CGI/1.1', 'HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE': 'en-US,en;
    q=0.8', 'CONTENT_TYPE': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded', 'AUTH_DOMAIN': 'gmail.com'}
    DEBUG    2011-09-28 18:30:56,671 dev_appserver.py:2721] Reusing main() function of module "google.appengine.ext.mapr
    educe.main"
    DEBUG    2011-09-28 18:30:56,688 dev_appserver.py:2198] Could not import "_io": Disallowed C-extension or built-in m
    odule
    DEBUG    2011-09-28 18:30:56,689 util.py:105] Could not import BlobstoreLineInputReader from google.appengine.ext.ma
    preduce.input_readers. Will try recursively.
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/ost/dev/gae/google/appengine/ext/mapreduce/util.py", line 90, in for_name
        result = __import__(module_name, None, None, [short_name])
      File "/home/ost/dev/gae/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver.py", line 1538, in Decorate
        return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
      File "/home/ost/dev/gae/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver.py", line 2503, in load_module
        return self.FindAndLoadModule(submodule, fullname, search_path)
      File "/home/ost/dev/gae/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver.py", line 1538, in Decorate
        return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
      File "/home/ost/dev/gae/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver.py", line 2375, in FindAndLoadModule
        description)
      File "/home/ost/dev/gae/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver.py", line 1538, in Decorate
        return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
      File "/home/ost/dev/gae/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver.py", line 2318, in LoadModuleRestricted
        description)
      File "/home/ost/dev/gae/google/appengine/ext/mapreduce/input_readers.py", line 59, in <module>
        import zipfile
      File "/home/ost/dev/gae/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver.py", line 1538, in Decorate
        return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
      File "/home/ost/dev/gae/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver.py", line 2503, in load_module
        return self.FindAndLoadModule(submodule, fullname, search_path)
      File "/home/ost/dev/gae/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver.py", line 1538, in Decorate
        return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
      File "/home/ost/dev/gae/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver.py", line 2375, in FindAndLoadModule
        description)
      File "/home/ost/dev/gae/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver.py", line 1538, in Decorate
        return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
      File "/home/ost/dev/gae/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver.py", line 2318, in LoadModuleRestricted
        description)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/zipfile.py", line 6, in <module>
        import io
      File "/home/ost/dev/gae/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver.py", line 1538, in Decorate
        return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
      File "/home/ost/dev/gae/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver.py", line 2503, in load_module
        return self.FindAndLoadModule(submodule, fullname, search_path)
      File "/home/ost/dev/gae/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver.py", line 1538, in Decorate
        return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
      File "/home/ost/dev/gae/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver.py", line 2375, in FindAndLoadModule
        description)
      File "/home/ost/dev/gae/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver.py", line 1538, in Decorate
        return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
      File "/home/ost/dev/gae/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver.py", line 2318, in LoadModuleRestricted
        description)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/io.py", line 60, in <module>
        import _io
    ImportError: No module named _io
    DEBUG    2011-09-28 18:30:56,698 dev_appserver.py:2198] Could not import "_io": Disallowed C-extension or built-in m
    odule
    DEBUG    2011-09-28 18:30:56,698 util.py:105] Could not import input_readers from google.appengine.ext.mapreduce. Wi
    ll try recursively.
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/ost/dev/gae/google/appengine/ext/mapreduce/util.py", line 90, in for_name
        result = __import__(module_name, None, None, [short_name])
      File "/home/ost/dev/gae/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver.py", line 1538, in Decorate
        return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
      File "/home/ost/dev/gae/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver.py", line 2503, in load_module
        return self.FindAndLoadModule(submodule, fullname, search_path)
      File "/home/ost/dev/gae/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver.py", line 1538, in Decorate
        return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
      File "/home/ost/dev/gae/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver.py", line 2375, in FindAndLoadModule
        description)
      File "/home/ost/dev/gae/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver.py", line 1538, in Decorate
        return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
      File "/home/ost/dev/gae/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver.py", line 2318, in LoadModuleRestricted
        description)
      File "/home/ost/dev/gae/google/appengine/ext/mapreduce/input_readers.py", line 59, in <module>
        import zipfile
      File "/home/ost/dev/gae/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver.py", line 1538, in Decorate
        return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
      File "/home/ost/dev/gae/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver.py", line 2503, in load_module
        return self.FindAndLoadModule(submodule, fullname, search_path)
      File "/home/ost/dev/gae/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver.py", line 1538, in Decorate
        return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
      File "/home/ost/dev/gae/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver.py", line 2375, in FindAndLoadModule
        description)
      File "/home/ost/dev/gae/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver.py", line 1538, in Decorate
        return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
      File "/home/ost/dev/gae/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver.py", line 2318, in LoadModuleRestricted
        description)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/zipfile.py", line 6, in <module>
        import io
      File "/home/ost/dev/gae/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver.py", line 1538, in Decorate
        return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
      File "/home/ost/dev/gae/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver.py", line 2503, in load_module
        return self.FindAndLoadModule(submodule, fullname, search_path)
      File "/home/ost/dev/gae/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver.py", line 1538, in Decorate
        return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
      File "/home/ost/dev/gae/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver.py", line 2375, in FindAndLoadModule
        description)
      File "/home/ost/dev/gae/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver.py", line 1538, in Decorate
        return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
      File "/home/ost/dev/gae/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver.py", line 2318, in LoadModuleRestricted
        description)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/io.py", line 60, in <module>
        import _io
    ImportError: No module named _io
    ERROR    2011-09-28 18:30:56,702 base_handler.py:140] Error in JsonHandler, returning exception.
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/ost/dev/gae/google/appengine/ext/mapreduce/base_handler.py", line 133, in _handle_wrapper
        self.handle()
      File "/home/ost/dev/gae/google/appengine/ext/mapreduce/handlers.py", line 762, in handle
        _app=mapper_params.get("_app"))
      File "/home/ost/dev/gae/google/appengine/ext/mapreduce/handlers.py", line 826, in _start_map
        mapper_input_reader_class = mapper_spec.input_reader_class()
      File "/home/ost/dev/gae/google/appengine/ext/mapreduce/model.py", line 408, in input_reader_class
        return util.for_name(self.input_reader_spec)
      File "/home/ost/dev/gae/google/appengine/ext/mapreduce/util.py", line 109, in for_name
        module = for_name(module_name, recursive=True)
      File "/home/ost/dev/gae/google/appengine/ext/mapreduce/util.py", line 117, in for_name
        short_name, module_name))
    ImportError: Could not find 'input_readers' on path 'google.appengine.ext.mapreduce' (????)
    INFO     2011-09-28 18:30:56,710 dev_appserver.py:4248] "POST /mapreduce/command/start_job HTTP/1.1" 200 -
    DEBUG    2011-09-28 18:30:56,711 dev_appserver_index.py:172] No need to update index.yaml
```

Comment: It seems likely something's wrong with your local SDK - have you checked if `google/appengine/ext/mapreduce/input_readers.py` (and the `__init__.py` file in the same directory) exist and are readable?

Answer (score 1):

This may be the same problem I was having -- I was using the 2.7 version of the Python Interpreter in my local environment. When I switched to 2.5, it works fine.