# Getting error "ImportError: Could not find 'input_readers' on path 'map reduce'" trying to start mapReduce job

Tags: google-app-engine, mapreduce

I'm getting this error... "ImportError: Could not find 'input_readers' on path 'map reduce'" when trying to Run my map reduce job via the http://localhost:8080/mapreduce launcher page.

It looks like my problem is similar to this post, [AppEngine mapper API import error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7587675/appengine-mapper-api-import-error).  Unfortunately, no definitive answers were given.

I've simplified it down to this tiny testmapreduce.py:

```
from google.appengine.ext import db

class TestEntity(db.Model):
    value = db.StringProperty()

def mapperhandler(test):
    print test.value
    return
```

And my mapreduce.yaml:

```
mapreduce:
- name: Simplest MapReduce
  mapper:
    handler: testmapreduce.mapperhandler
    input_reader: mapreduce.input_readers.DatastoreInputReader
    params:
    - name: entity_kind
      default: testmapreduce.TestEntity
```

One possible clue is the presence of __init__.py has no effect (whether in the project root, the mapreduce directory, or both).  I'm sure I'm making a beginner mistake, but over the last couple of days I have read every bit of documentation, and all the examples I can find.     Thanks.

UPDATE:
I get the same error trying to invoke it via...

```
control.start_map(
   "Give awards",
   "testmapreduce.mapperhandler",
   "mapreduce.input_readers.DatastoreInputReader",
   {"entity_kind": "testmapreduce.TestEntity"},
   shard_count=10)
```

UPDATE:
As requested, the stack trace -- let me know what else would be helpful...

```
ERROR    2011-10-16 17:09:27,216 _webapp25.py:464] Could not find 'input_readers' on path 'mapreduce'
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/Develop/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/webapp/_webapp25.py", line 701, in __call__
   handler.get(*groups)
 File "/Users/lc/PycharmProjects/mrtest/testmapreduce.py", line 22, in get
   shard_count=10)      # handle web form test interface
 File "/Users/lc/PycharmProjects/mrtest/mapreduce/control.py", line 94, in start_map
   transactional=transactional)
 File "/Users/lc/PycharmProjects/mrtest/mapreduce/handlers.py", line 811, in _start_map
   mapper_input_reader_class = mapper_spec.input_reader_class()
 File "/Users/lc/PycharmProjects/mrtest/mapreduce/model.py", line 393, in input_reader_class
   return util.for_name(self.input_reader_spec)
 File "/Users/lc/PycharmProjects/mrtest/mapreduce/util.py", line 94, in for_name
   module = for_name(module_name, recursive=True)
 File "/Users/lc/PycharmProjects/mrtest/mapreduce/util.py", line 102, in for_name
   short_name, module_name))
ImportError: Could not find 'input_readers' on path 'mapreduce'
INFO     2011-10-16 22:09:27,253 dev_appserver.py:4247] "GET /giveawards HTTP/1.1" 500 -
```

Comment: Please include the original stacktrace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem turned out to be that I was using the 2.7 version of the Python Interpreter in my local environment. When I switched to 2.5, it works fine.